# Adding methods to Freezed Class

Tags: flutter, freezed, flutter-freezed

I'm using [freezed package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#how-copywith-works) to generate data classes.

The package support disabling the copyWith generation using `@Freezed(copyWith: false)` annotation.

I want to implement a custom `copyWith` to my Freezed data class. Here is my code:

```
@Freezed(copyWith: false)
class AuthenticationState with _$AuthenticationState {
  const factory AuthenticationState({
    String? userId,
    ErrorObject? errorObject,
  }) = _AuthenticationState;

  AuthenticationState copyWith({
    String? userId,
    ErrorObject? errorObject,
  }) {
    return AuthenticationState(
      userId: userId ?? this.userId,
      errorObject: errorObject, // resets if not provided
    );
  }
}
```

I generation runs successfully and there are no static analysis errors.

But when I run the app, I'm getting this error:

> authentication_bloc.freezed.dart:32:7: Error: The non-abstract class
> '_$_AuthenticationState' is missing implementations for these members:
>
> - AuthenticationState.copyWith Try to either
> - provide an implementation,
> - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
> - mark the class as abstract, or
> - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.
>
> class _$_AuthenticationState implements _AuthenticationState {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lib/authentication/bloc/authentication_state.dart:28:23: Context:
> 'AuthenticationState.copyWith' is defined here.

**What is the problem? How to implement custom `copyWith` in Freezed classes?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are adding methods to your freezed-model, as you are in this case, you have to define a private constructor.

So, add the line below, re-generate and everything should work:

```
const AuthenticationState._();
```

I.e.:

```
@Freezed(copyWith: false)
class AuthenticationState with _$AuthenticationState {

  const AuthenticationState._(); // ADD THIS LINE

  const factory AuthenticationState({
    String? userId,
    ErrorObject? errorObject,
  }) = _AuthenticationState;

  ...
}
```

This is a requirement posed by the freezed-package. See [official documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#adding-getters-and-methods-to-our-models).

Comment: Why do I have to use private constructors?

Comment: Because that is a requirement from the freezed package. I haven't read the source code myself, but I'm guessing that it is a requirement for the code generation to work properly. https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#adding-getters-and-methods-to-our-models